# how to install ubuntu server on remote system through SSH

Tags: server, ssh

I am trying to install ubuntu server on remote system through SSH. Remote system is completely blank and is not having any os on it.
Can anyone please give some HINT how to do this??

Comment: You can't SSH into a server with no operating system whatsoever. Is this a dedicated server? Virtual Private Server? Through a hosting company or your own hardware? Do you have any physical access to it? Does anyone else?

Comment: its a dedicated server but I don't have access to it...

Comment: Is it through a hosting company? Do you have access to some sort of web-based control panel?

Comment: its a dedicated server with own hardware.. i have its ip details

Comment: But there is *no* operating system on it whatsoever?

Comment: no there is no operating system, I have only hardware, should there be some software initially so I can get connect to it??

Comment: I have one method that would work and is a possibility: you need to log onto the website of the hoster and activate the installation. Normally I'd expect the hoster to do this for you when a contract is signed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no physical access to the hardware, no web-based control panel, and there is no operating system whatsoever on the machine, then I don't know of any way to install an operating system on it remotely.

If you were able to install an operating system on this computer over the internet, so would *anyone in the world* with its IP address -- and computer systems generally don't allow that kind of unfettered remote access. (Not to mention it would need an operating system running in order to communicate across the internet!)

It sounds like you need to either gain physical access to the machine, or make contact with someone who can. Then you can install an operating system, a hypervisor, set up PXE-boot, or whatever setup you choose.

If you rent the server through a hosting company, you should contact them to discuss your options.